# How can I get else value when compare key of array and value?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

output my first array `$arr_val` :

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

output second array `$pecah_arr` :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Kunyit dipercaya sebagai salah satu rempah yang dapat mendukung kesehatan hingga untuk pengobatan
    [1] => Sayangnya, pemakaian yang keliru justru berdampak sebaliknya
    [2] => Seperti berita yang diangkat NBC News, seorang wanita asal San Diego yang menerima pengobatan kunyit intravena harus mengakhiri nyawa.
    [3] => Jade Erick meninggal 16 Maret lalu setelah pergi ke India untuk melakukan pengobatan rempah-rempah untuk penyakit eksim yang dideritanya.
)
```

I want to get output like this,
if value in `$arr_val` same with key of `$pecah_arr`, print the value that same.
but if value in `$arr_val` not same with key of `$pecah_arr`, print the value that not same.

my logic like this:

```
    $hasil_ringkasan=array();
    foreach ($arr_val as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($pecah_arr as $key2 => $value2) {
            if($value==$key2){
                $no_doc=$value+1;
                array_push($hasil_ringkasan, $value2);
                //INSERT KE DB untuk Learning
                $q=$this->db->query("INSERT INTO tb_sementara 
                VALUES('$key2[$value]','$no_doc','$fitur1_uji[$value]','$fitur2_uji[$value]',
                    '$fitur3_uji[$value]','$fitur4_uji[$value]','$fitur5_uji[$value]','$fitur6_uji[$value]','ringkasan')");

                }else{
                // INSERT KE DB untuk Learning
                $q=$this->db->query("INSERT INTO tb_sementara 
                VALUES('$key2[$value]','$no_doc','$fitur1_uji[$value]','$fitur2_uji[$value]',
                    '$fitur3_uji[$value]','$fitur4_uji[$value]','$fitur5_uji[$value]','$fitur6_uji[$value]','bukan') 
                ");
            }

        }
    }
```

Although in `if` had worked, but I dont know why in `else` dont work.
thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to iterate over $arr_val. Use in_array() instead.

```
$hasil_ringkasan=array();
    foreach ($pecah_arr as $key2 => $value2) {
        if(in_array($key2,$arr_val)){
            $no_doc=$value+1;
            array_push($hasil_ringkasan, $value2);
            //INSERT KE DB untuk Learning
            $q=$this->db->query("INSERT INTO tb_sementara 
            VALUES('$key2[$value]','$no_doc','$fitur1_uji[$value]','$fitur2_uji[$value]',
                '$fitur3_uji[$value]','$fitur4_uji[$value]','$fitur5_uji[$value]','$fitur6_uji[$value]','ringkasan')");

            }else{
            // INSERT KE DB untuk Learning
            $q=$this->db->query("INSERT INTO tb_sementara 
            VALUES('$key2[$value]','$no_doc','$fitur1_uji[$value]','$fitur2_uji[$value]',
                '$fitur3_uji[$value]','$fitur4_uji[$value]','$fitur5_uji[$value]','$fitur6_uji[$value]','bukan') 
            ");
        }


}
```

Comment: I also think $key2[$value] is wrong in your code. Instead, use $pecah_arr[$key2] in if and else

Comment: Hi @Rachmad..Can you please accept the answer if it helped you?

Comment: @Shuci Sethi, ok thanks I just solved my problem ,thanks for your help..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$same     = array_intersect($arr_val, array_keys($pecah_arr));
$not_same = array_diff($arr_val, array_keys($pecah_arr));

foreach ($same as $index) {
    // do what you want on same values using $pecah_arr[$index] value
}

foreach ($not_same as $index) {
    // do what you want on NOT same values using $pecah_arr[$index] value
}
```